# How to remove the indentation of the section-title second line using droit-fr class?

Tags: indentation, section-titles

I am using the `droit-fr` class, and I need **only** section titles not to be indented on the second line (and the following).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french,twoside,footnotereset=true,versetitle=true]{droit-fr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\chapitre{This chapter title is good}

\section{I want this title no to be indent on the second line and following}

\paragraphe{The title format is good and can be intended on each line}

\souspara{The title format is good and can be intended on each line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove indentation of second line of section headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283510/remove-indentation-of-second-line-of-section-headers)

Comment: Voting to keep this question open since it is not completely trivial or obvious how to adapt the answer in the linked question to this case where the effect should be restricted to a particular heading `\section` (and with a different document class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283521/) for your question, something like this would work, even if it might not be particularly elegant:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french,twoside,versetitle=true]{droit-fr}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
\bgroup
\def\@hangfrom##1{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{##1}}%
      \hangindent 0pt%\wd\@tempboxa
      \noindent\box\@tempboxa}
\oldsection{#1}
\egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapitre{This chapter title is good}

\section{I want this title no to be indent on the second line and following}

\paragraphe{The title format is good and can be intended on each line}

\souspara{The title format is good and can be intended on each line}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much!